# TSQL Rellenar valores nulls con el último valor no null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de rellenar registros de una columna donde tengo valores nulls de forma entrecortada con el último valor no null de la misma columna (de abajo hacia arriba). Les muestro una imagen de lo que quiero . Uso TSQL

```
select a.PERIODO,a.RUC,b.COD_EST,b.ESTADO 
from #temp2 a
left join db_ocg.prub.Hist_Estado b
on a.ruc = b.ruc and a.periodo = b.periodo
where a.RUC in (10484021843,10211107940,10076689437)
order by 2,1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Una forma, es numerar mediante  `ROW_NUMBER()` por grupo de `a.PERIODO` y `a.RUC` y en orden descendente por `b.COD_EST`, esto hará que las filas de interés tengan el número 1, por lo que simplemente habría luego que filtrarlas en una subconsulta:

```
select *
       from (
            select a.PERIODO,
                   a.RUC,
                   b.COD_EST,
                   b.ESTADO
                   ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY a.PERIODO, a.RUC ORDER BY b.COD_EST DESC) as 'RN'
                   from #temp2 a
                   left join db_ocg.prub.Hist_Estado b
                        on a.ruc = b.ruc and a.periodo = b.periodo
                   where a.RUC in (10484021843,10211107940,10076689437)
       )
       where RN = 1
       order by 2,1
```